# How to add Image Upload with Froala in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, entity, froala

I'm trying to add Image Upload with Froala Editor to my Blog app.

My onPost method in NewPost.cshtml.cs file looks like this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadImageAsync(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest("No file uploaded");
        }

        try
        {
            var uploadResult = await _imageRepository.UploadAsync(file);

            if (uploadResult == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadResult.SecureUrl.AbsoluteUri))
            {
                return BadRequest("Failed to upload image");
            }

            return new JsonResult(new { url = uploadResult.SecureUrl.AbsoluteUri });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception here
            return BadRequest("An error occurred while uploading the image");
        }
    }
```

And in my NewPost.cshtml file js script looks like this:

```
    <script>
        var editor = new FroalaEditor('#content', {
            height: 300,
            imageUploadURL: '/Admin/NewPost?handler=OnPostUploadImageAsync',


        })


        document.getElementById('featuredImageUpload').addEventListener('change', function () {
            var input = this;
            var imgPreview = document.getElementById('featuredImagePreview');
            var imageURLInput = document.getElementById('featuredImageURL');

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    imgPreview.src = e.target.result;
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

                imageURLInput.value = '@ViewData["FeaturedImageURL"]';
            }
        });  
    </script>
```

Now when i try to upload an image by froala I get '**Error during file upload**' and in Chrome Console
**POST https://localhost:7006/Admin/NewPost?handler=OnPostUploadImageAsync 400 (Bad Request)**

When I tried debugging I saw that the code in NewPost.cshtml.cs is unreachable, but I still did not find a solution.

Comment: In your Chrome console try https://localhost:706/Admin/NewPost?handler=UploadImageAsync.